# How to save ms of ping in in txt file?

Tags: batch-file, ping

I want to use for example:

```
ping google.com -t
```

> Antwort von 193.99.144.80: Bytes=32 Zeit=17ms TTL=244

and want to save only the **ms** in a textfile.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
set ip=www.google.com
ping %ip% -t |repl ".*?=.*?=([0-9]*).*TTL=.*" "$1" A >>textfile.txt
```

Comment: what is the `repl.bat` exactly doing?

Comment: It extracts the numbers after the second equals sign, in lines that contain `TTL=`

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=7delims== " %%a in ('ping google.com^|find /i "Antwort"') do set ms=%%a
echo %ms%
set "ms=%ms:~0,-2%"
echo %ms%
```

take your pick of what format you want...

If you want the result from the final line (average is the 6th item in English) then use `tokens=6` and remove the `^find /i "Antwort"`

Comment: The `for` command isn't going to spit anything out because the `ping` command never ends.

Comment: @foxidrive : fair enough. modified, but it seems to make little sense to simply `ping` endlessly. Without further details...